# Reporting heteroscedasticity-robust standard errors in modelsummary for panel data (plm)

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, modelsummary

I encounter a problem with the reporting of heteroscedasticity-robust standard errors for a panel data regression ([plm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/plm.pdf)) in the output with [modelsummary](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modelsummary/modelsummary.pdf). For a simple linear regression the reporting works without problems, for a linear panel data regression not.

Attached is an example syntax for the Grunfeld dataset in the plm package.

```
data("Grunfeld")

lm <- lm(value ~
           capital + inv,
         data = Grunfeld
           )

summary(lm)
coeftest(lm, vcov =
           vcovHC(lm, type = "HC1"))

re <- plm(value ~
            capital + inv
          , data = Grunfeld
          , model = "random"
          , effect = "twoways"
)

summary(re)
coeftest(re, vcov =
           vcovHC(re, type = "HC1"))
```

Both outputs with heteroscedasticity-robust standard errors should look like this:

[image]

However, when I report the model outputs in modelsummary, only for the simple linear regression the heteroscedasticity-robust standard errors are reported correctly. Most disturbingly, the output still lists the correction to the standard errors for the plm regression in the last line.

```
modelsummary::msummary(list(
  "lm" = lm
  , "random effects" = re
  ),
  coef_map = c(
  "(Intercept)" = "Intercept"
  , "capital" = "Capital"
  , "inv" = "Investment"
  ),
  stars = TRUE,
  statistic = c(
    "p.value"
    , "conf.int"
    , "std.error"
    ),
  vcov = "HC1"
  )
```

[image]

Can anyone please help me to fix this error? Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: I've been playing around with this and I wonder if it may be due to the "plm" class of the `re` model. When inserting two "lm" class models into the function (as a test), the function correctly applies the correction to both models.

Comment: `modelsummary` uses the `parameters` argument to extract standard errors from model objects. `parameters` does not currently support this functionality for `plm()` models, and it ignores the `vcov` argument altogether and returns a numeric vector of standard errors, so there's no way for `modelsummary` to know those are not actually HC1. I opened an issue on the `parameters` development site. You can follow progress here: https://github.com/easystats/parameters/issues/911

Comment: @Vincent Note, that calling `vcovHC` on a `"plm"` object calls `plm::vcovHC` and not `sandwich::vcovHC`.

Comment: @Quinton.Quagliano: It is the same for all model arguments in plm, even for the naive pooling.

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf, that's very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the `vcov`.

```
re$vcov <- plm::vcovHC(re, type = "HC1")

modelsummary::msummary(list(lm = lm, `random effects` = re), 
    coef_map = c(`(Intercept)` = "Intercept", capital = "Capital", 
        inv = "Investment"), stars = TRUE, statistic = c("p.value", 
        "conf.int", "std.error"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick workaround.